# viewModelScope not recognized - unresolved reference

Tags: android, kotlin, viewmodel

I was checking for answers to my question and I found that is version problem, but i cant check the correct versions that i have to use.. maybe some advices? Thanks in advance.

My build:

```
implementation "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jdk7:$kotlin_version" (1.3.72)

implementation "androidx.core:core-ktx:$androidXVersion" (1.0.2)
implementation "androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-extensions:$archLifecycleVersion" (2.2.0)
implementation "androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-viewmodel-ktx:$archLifecycleVersion" (2.2.0)
kapt "androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-compiler:$archLifecycleVersion" (2.2.0)

classpath "com.android.tools.build:gradle:$gradle_version" (3.5.3)
classpath "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-gradle-plugin:$kotlin_version" (1.3.72)
```

I have an example, and the difference is androidXversion is 1.0.0, gradle version is 3.3.2 and kotlin version is 1.3.5

Comment: It should highlight out-of-date ones and tell you the latest if you hover over them.

Comment: Android build tools are at '4.0.1'. `core-ktx` is at 1.3.1. The others look OK. You can update Kotlin if you like, but that's not the issue. Kotlin is at 1.4.10. You can now omit the Kotlin stdlib line from your dependencies as that's handled by the plugin. I'm using Gradle 6.1.1.

Comment: I missed livedata reference :(

Answer (score 0):

You can try to hardcode the gradle_version and other versions into the dependency string, like

`classpath "com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.3.2"`